# Unable to post multiple files using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to post multiple files by implementing 3 input file html controls but when data is posted only one file[index] is received and others are not received.
Here is my Html form

```
      <form action="" id="form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" id="abtitle" name="abouttitle" placeholder="Title" required />
      <textarea id="msg" name="aboutmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
          <p><input type="file" name="pic1" id="pic1" /></p>
            <p><input type="file" name="pic2" id="pic2" /></p>
            <p><input type="file" name="pic3" id="pic3" /></p>
              <input type="button" name="contactsubmit" id="contactbtn" value="Submit"/>
    </form>    

   <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#contactbtn").click(function(){
var pic1 = $('#pic1').prop('files')[0];
 var pic2 = $('#pic2').prop('files')[0];
 var pic3 = $('#pic3').prop('files')[0];
 var title=$("#abtitle").val();
    var msg=$("#msg").val();
 var form_data = new FormData();


form_data.append('Title',title);
form_data.append('Msg',msg);                  
form_data.append('file1',pic1);
form_data1.append('file2',pic2);  
form_data.append('file3',pic3);

            $.ajax({
     url: "../../code/aboutuscode.php", 
     type: "POST",             
     data: form_data, 
     contentType: false,       
     cache: false,             
     processData:false,        
     success: function(data) 
     {

      alert(data);
       }
      });
```

"aboutuscode.php"

```
     <?php $tmpfile1=$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

$tmpfile2=$_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];
$tmpfile1.=$tmpfile2;
echo $tmpfile1;
    ?>
```

Comment: you're using `pic2`, but are sending `file2`.

Comment: @MarcB  I have corrected file1 and file2 but it is still not working. I am getting file1 index only not more than one file

Comment: so start debugging: `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what you really received.

Comment: Hey @MarcB after dump it is saying  
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: then no files were upload, or you're doing the upload incorrectly.

Comment: Hey @MarcB it is working correctly on Fire Fox but not on Chrome On Firefox i received this:
array (size=2)
  'file1' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '34.jpg' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2919.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 620888
  'file2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'Desert.jpg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2929.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 84594